# Firefox DOMParser problem

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, parsing

For some reason DOMParser is adding some additional #text elements for each newline `\n` for this url

http://rt.com/Root.rss

...as well as many other RSS I've tried. I checked cnn/bbc feeds, they don't have newlines and dom parser handling them nicely. So I have to add the following before parsing it

```
var xmlText = htmlText.replace(/\n[ ]*/g, "");
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml");
```

Server is returning text/xml.

```
var channel = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0];
```

this returning `\n` without my code above and `channel` with correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason DOMParser is adding some additional #text elements for each newline \n for this url

that is standard behaviour. only IE ignores whithespace between Element Nodes. ([XML Whitespace Handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space), [Whitespace @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762315%28VS.85%29.aspx), [Whitespace @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Whitespace_in_the_DOM))

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's what XML parsers are supposed to do by default. Get used to walking through child nodes checking to see whether they're elements (`nodeType===1`) or text nodes (`3`).

From Firefox 3.5 you get the [Element Traversal API](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/), giving you properties like `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling`. This makes walking over the DOM whilst ignoring whitespace easier. Alternatively you could use XPath (`doc.evaluate`) to find the elements you want.

If you want to remove whitespace nodes for good, it's a much better idea to do it on the parsed DOM than by using a regex hack:

```
function removeWhitespace(node) {
    for (var i= node.childNodes.length; i-->0;) {
        var child= node.childNodes[i];
        if (child.nodeType===3 && child.data.match(/^\s*$/))
            node.removeChild(child);
        if (child.nodeType===1)
            removeWhitespace(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firefox also has the .children property, which is a collection of all element children.

Comment: Instead of '3' and '1' you can use 'Node.TEXT_NODE' and 'Node.ELEMENT_NODE', respectively.

Comment: @Westy92: you may not be able to, depending on what versions of IE you need to be compatible with.

Comment: @bobince: you're right.  Disregard my previous comment, or define your own Node constant to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? Do you wish to *not* use the workaround? I think the workaround is necessary as the parser is working as expected.

Comment: My thoughts are the parser is not working as expected and the workaround is somewhat artificial. The parser should not put `\n` elements, so I though maybe I'm misusing the parser functionality. Really want to avoid such workarounds.