# How to build an HTML DOM from a multiline string and access child elements in Jest?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jestjs, jsdom

##### Problem:

I'm trying to build an *HTML* DOM from a **multiline string** in *Jest* in order to test a browser extension.

However, when I try to access the child elements of the DOM, they are being returned as strings instead of DOM nodes.

##### What I've tried:

I have tried multiple approaches, but they all seem to have the same issue.

```js
const html = `
<div id="id1">
<p id="id2">
<span id="id3">Hello World</span>
</p>
</div>
`

const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = html.trim()
console.log(template.content.firstChild?.firstChild) // Text {Symbol(impl): TextImpl}

const htmlParser = new DOMParser()
const parsed = htmlParser.parseFromString(html.trim(), 'text/html')
console.log(parsed.body.firstChild?.firstChild) // Text {Symbol(impl): TextImpl}

const dom = new JSDOM(html.trim())
console.log(dom.window.document.body.firstChild?.firstChild) // Text {Symbol(impl): TextImpl}
```

(And of course the `testEnvironment: "jsdom"` in `jest.config.js`)

#### Question:

Is there a way to correctly build an HTML DOM from a multiline string and access its child elements in Jest?

Comment: With the caveat that I don't know anything about jest: what exactly do you expect the output to be? The first child of the first child of the template, for example, is a whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096044/7186622) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793630/7186622):

> The browser insert a text node when there are white spaces or new lines in your code. You are targeting one of those.

To skip those *text nodes*, you can use `template.content.firstElementChild?.firstElementChild` to skip the *text nodes*.

---

You can try without any whitespaces like:

```js
const html = `<div id="id1"><p id="id2"><span id="id3">Hello World</span></p></div>
```

Or by doing a regex/replace function to remove all useless whitespaces, but for me the best solution will to use "querySelector"